# [Python ASN1]: GeneralizedTime pyasn1 implementation

Tags: pyasn1

Here is my asn1 grammar representation:-

```
MiepPullWtdr ::= [0] SEQUENCE
{
    timeStamp                   [8]   GeneralizedTime
}
```

I need help in implementing the same using pyasn1.

Here is my code snippet:-

```
from pyasn1.type import univ, namedtype, tag, char, namedval, useful

class MiepPullWtdr(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(namedtype.NamedType('timeStamp', useful.GeneralizedTime().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 8)))

)

miepPullWtdr = MiepPullWtdr()
miepPullWtdr.setComponentByName('timeStamp', '201103081200Z')
print(miepPullWtdr.prettyPrint())
```

I also tried,

```
componentType  = namedtype.NamedTypes(namedtype.NamedType('timeStamp',useful.GeneralizedTime().tagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 8)))
```

Both doesn't work and gives a weird error regrading Syntax error:-

```
miepPullWtdr = MiepPullWtdr()
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have checked the commas and brackets. All seem to be correct.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Your code worked for me as soon as I fixed the dangling parenthesis at the "componentType" line.

Comment: @IlyaEtingof: Can u please provide the same as an answer here. I would highly appreciate that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code except for the dangling parenthesis of the `componentType` fixed. Works for me:

```
from pyasn1.type import univ, namedtype, tag, namedval, useful

class MiepPullWtdr(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
        namedtype.NamedType('timeStamp', useful.GeneralizedTime().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 8)))
    )

miepPullWtdr = MiepPullWtdr()
miepPullWtdr.setComponentByName('timeStamp', '201103081200Z')

print(miepPullWtdr.prettyPrint())
```